# prebuilding nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models linked with a has_many. The parent model has accepts_nested_attributes_for the child model.

According to all the tutorials and docs I can find, when using f.fields_for on the child model, it will only display fields if there are child models in existance. That works, the part that doesn't work is building empty children.

```
3.times { @post.comments.build }
```

Should, as I understand, create 3 empty, associated models and show 3 sets of form fields for them automatically.

It doesn't matter if I use the .build method, Model.new method or anything else, I cannot get it to show any form fields.

I must be doing something wrong but it's gonna take the collective genius of stackoverflow to show me :P

Please see the [code on gist](https://gist.github.com/8fd7312e222c548b37fe).

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your view code?

Comment: Certainly, I meant to do that before. Added a gist on the original article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
- f.fields_for :input_items do |item|
```

With:

```
= f.fields_for :input_items do |item|
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets it to at least output one set of fields. It still doesn't seem to show more than one even though I have build 3 children. It's not a big problem only having one, I'm just curious now.

Comment: I can't see where you have the 3.times {} in your gist :)